# Get the name of the package that TinyTest is testing

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, tinytest

I need to determine the name of the Meteor package that a given test file is currently testing, so that I can derive the path to assets. For example, if we're testing fortawesome:fontawesome, the assets will be accessible at `/packages/fortawesome_fontawesome/`.

How can I get the name of the very package that [TinyTest](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/tinytest) is testing?

**package.js**:

```
Package.onTest(function (api) {
  api.use(packageName, where);
  api.use(['tinytest', 'http'], 'client');

  api.addFiles('test.js', 'client');
});
```

**test.js**:

```
var packageName = ???;
HTTP.get('/packages/' + packageName.replace(':', '_') + '/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff');
```

Comment: [MeteorTesting.com](http://meteortesting.com) author @Sam-Hatoum might know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an API call for this, but the `Package` object contains all loaded packages, including one that starts with `local-test`, which has so far been the tested package:

[image]

Therefore,

```
var packageName = _.find(Object.keys(Package), function(p) {
  return p.search(/local-test/) > -1
}).replace('local-test:', '');
```

Note however that for some mysterious reason, the `local-test:<your_package>` package isn't loaded before the first Tinytest call, so careful where you place the code above.